# SQL - Repeat a row with union

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

I have a test table with 4 rows of (id, fsn, owner, IR, NI)

```
id: 1, fsn: 123, owner: jones, IR: 1000, NI: 2350
id: 2, fsn: 345, owner: smith, IR: 0, NI: 50
id: 3, fsn: 567, owner: casey, IR: 200, NI: 0,
id: 4, fsn: 789, owner: brown, IR: 400, NI: 0
```

I need to split these on the IR/NI fields so that I have a record for each IR and NI field that is not 0 because I need to process each type separately with Joins etc. So my final output at this point **should** be

```
id: 2, fsn: 345, owner: smith, IR: 0, NI: 50
id: 3, fsn: 567, owner: casey, IR: 200, NI: 0,
id: 4, fsn: 789, owner: brown, IR: 400, NI: 0,
id: 1, fsn: 123, owner: jones, IR: 1000, NI: 2350,
id: 1, fsn: 123, owner: jones, IR: 1000, NI: 2350
```

I thought the following would accomplish that split but it doesn't repeat the row like I need.

```
SELECT *
FROM farms
WHERE IR != 0

UNION

SELECT *
FROM farms
WHERE NI != 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you'd want this row doubled, but there's an easy way to solve it: use the `union all` set operator, which acts like the `union` operator but does not remove duplicates:

```
SELECT *
FROM farms
WHERE IR != 0

UNION ALL  -- Here!

SELECT *
FROM farms
WHERE NI != 0
```

Comment: This is a farms table and I need to manufacture a Units table (which are farms divided by Practice (Irrigated and NonIrrigated). There are 63 other fields I will have to include on each and then hand off to the API. Thanks!

Comment: Follow-up: Ultimately I will want to order the UNION ALL by id ... where do I put the ORDER BY?

Comment: @jgravois after the second query - it will sort the "unioned" results.

Answer (score 0):

You can have both the checks in one query.

```
SELECT *
FROM farms
WHERE  NI != 0 or IR != 0
```